# How get data from database column as a heading using Repeater in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asprepeater

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBUno.jpg) 
The Upper portion of present my database table structure and lower portion that in which form i want to show data.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th>Course Code</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Cr.Hours</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <asp:Repeater ID="outer" runat="server">

      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("[SpringFall]")%>' Style="text-align: center; display: none; font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'" ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"> </asp:Label>

          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="AllCcode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[Course_Code]") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="AllSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[Subject]") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="AllCrHr" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[Credit_Hours]") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="AllGrade" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[Total_Marks]") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here Is my code..bind repeater on button click event using c# with simple sql SELECT query.Any query for bind repeater with more efficient working and show data in given form.

```
protected void AttendencBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //  MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 8;
    conn.Open();
    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  Attendence where Roll_Number='" + Session["RollNumb"] + "' ", conn);
    dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    AttendencRpt.DataSource = dt;
    AttendencRpt.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is it that u want ?

Comment: and a `DataReader` is always better than a `DataAdapter` regarding performance

Comment: See Image for clarification.Repeater bind all  data from database but i want .a column that have same data in each row ..grouped and show on label at once..using repeater..

Comment: I've seen ur image but still don't understand ? U pointed out 2014 and 2015..So,what are u trying to achieve,can u explain in words ?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You also need to read about and start using parameterized queries. What you have is open to sql injection.

Comment: @AdeelRana,asSeanLange pointed out,your sql query looks horrible as it is open to sql injection :( .... Why not use parameters instead bro ? I know this is not ur main issue now but why to leave a loop hole ?? :)

Comment: i am trying to develop marks sheet .for this my database have 5 columns..c_code,Subject,Cr_hour,total marks and last column is year that have registered students from 2014 to 2018 .student who have register subject in 2014..show 2014 on top of table and below this the subjects and other related data show according to year..after show 2014 than same that like image show 2015 on top and than subject and other data that student learn in 2015 ..up to so on same like this till 2018... explain this according to ur logic ..

Comment: that is c# code     conn.Close();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  * from  [All_Semester_Result] where Roll_Number='" + Session["RollNumb"] + "'    ", conn);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            outer.DataSource = dt;
            outer.DataBind();
            conn.Close();

Comment: @zackraiyan according to ur answer use DataReader..also trying using DataReader..Now r u clear?

Comment: using a datareader is fast that's why i suggested...happy that u implemented it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this. First create a public variable in code behind.

```
public int currentYear = 2000;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Then change the Repeater to something like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myYear")).Year != currentYear && Container.ItemIndex > 0 ? "<tr><td colspan=\"5\">" + Eval("myYear") + "</td></tr>" : "" %>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    normal rows here
                </td>
            </tr>

            <%# currentYear = Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myYear")).Year %>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

What will happen is that the value of `currentYear` is compared to the current row value. If it does not match a new row will be created. Then the value of `currentYear` is updated to be checked in the next row bound to the Repeater.

Comment: Thnx for Suggestion near to my problem fell happy u understand this problem

Comment: Data in the column like this Fall(2014) Fall(2014) Spring(2015) Spring(2015) Fall(2015) Fall(2015) Spring(2016) Fall(2016) Spring(2017) Fall(2017)   how bind repeater for get this data one time.

Comment: You have to make sure that `currentYear` becomes the delimiter on which to split your data in the Repeater. Therefore there has to be a column in the dataset that acts as that delimiter, like a DateTime field.